# Collision dubbels up overtime you restart the game

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have this onCollision function but every time the game starts over the collision double up

```
local function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
        local obj1 = event.object1; 
        local obj2 = event.object2; 

    if obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud1" then   
        MinLife()

        elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud2" then
        pontsMin10()

        elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud3" then
        pontsMin20()

        elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "GCloud1" then
        pontsplus50()

        elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "bla" then
        score = score - 20

        end
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )

function scene:exitScene( event )
Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

is there any reason for this to happen ?

Comment: what does double up mean?

Comment: the 1st time i start the game and i hit "MinLife()" it take one life off but when you restart the game 'gameover.lua->start.lua->game.lua' when you hit "MinLife()" it takes 2 lives off, the 3th time you restart 3 lifes and so on.

Comment: If the code being run there, specifically the addEventListener bit, happens more than once each event will trigger your callback N times. Is that code being run each time the game starts over? Is your exitScene/removeEventListener function perhaps not being called correctly?

Comment: Why are using Runtime on your collision when you can use it on the jetplayer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `local function onCollision(event)` is outside of the other functions.

Maybe the problem is in your `Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )`, it can't find the `onCollision` because it is inside on the other functions.

Comment: thats is i never thought of that :D it was placed in the function scene:enterScene( event )

Comment: hi this is driving me absolutely crazy  when i place the code outside the "function scene:enterScene( event )" it works 2 times but the 3th time i restart the game is doing absolutely nothing, any more handy tips ?

Comment: fixed it by adding "storyboard.removeScene( "game" ) & storyboard.purgeScene("game")" to "scene:didExitScene( event )"

Answer (score 0):

```
    if obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud1" then MinLife()
elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud2" then pontsMin10()
elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "BCloud3" then pontsMin20()
elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "GCloud1" then pontsplus50()
elseif obj1.name == "jetplayer" and obj2.name == "bla"     then score = score - 20
end
```

FYI, this is a lot of redundant tests for `obj1.name == "jetplayer"`. I'd rewrite that code to do the test once:

```
    if obj1.name == "jetplayer" then
        if     obj2.name == "BCloud1" then MinLife()
        elseif obj2.name == "BCloud2" then pontsMin10()
        elseif obj2.name == "BCloud3" then pontsMin20()
        elseif obj2.name == "GCloud1" then pontsplus50()
        elseif obj2.name == "bla"     then score = score - 20
        end
    end
```

> the 1st time i start the game and i hit "MinLife()" it take one life off but when you restart the game 'gameover.lua->start.lua->game.lua' when you hit "MinLife()" it takes 2 lives off, the 3th time you restart 3 lifes and so on

You don't show `MinLife`, so we have no way of knowing if the bug is in that code. I'd check that you're not adding your collision handler more than once (e.g. make sure your exitScene handler is getting hit, etc.)